# Custom HTML in Joomla Template Manager

Tags: image, templates, joomla, cdata

While developing a **Joomla** Template, i got stuck on this question.

Every **Joomla** Module has a manifest. In that manifest you can set your **Paramaters** for your template with **Field** and **Fieldset** types. Is it possible to add a custom image in these sections? I tried `CDATA` for this but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried this with a template, only a plugin and module, but I believe it's still the same concept.

Create a new folder in your template folder and name it "**elements**".

Then, in your *template.xml* file, find the `<fieldset>` that the parameter belongs to and add the following inside the tag:

```
addfieldpath="/modules/mod_social_slider/fields"
```

You now need to add a new parameter field like so:

```
<field name="image" type="custom" default="" label="" description="" />
```

Now, create a new PHP and place it inside your newly created "**elements**" folder and call it "**custom.php**". Then add the following code:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class JFormFieldCustom extends JFormField {

    protected $type = 'Custom';

    protected function getInput() {
        return '<img src="' . JUri::root() . 'templates/your_template/images/image.jpg" alt="" />';
    }

}
?>
```

Note that I haven't tested this so let me know if it works or not

Comment: Ok that worked. and love it thanks.
addfieldpath="/templates/templateName/elements" if you want to use it in youre template.

Comment: Ahh sorry, forgot to change the path for you. Took it from my module as I needed something similar. Glad it worked :)