# XML field checkboxes with SQL

Tags: xml, joomla, joomla3.0

I am trying to create list of article to choose from (multiple select checkbox), but so far I am not able to do so, or find a solution on net. So far I just have this:

```
 <field name="title" type="sql" default="10" label="Select an article" query="SELECT id AS value, title FROM #__content" ></field>
```

It is not much at all, but it is working. The problem is, that I am getting a list, where I can click on one article, and that is it. How can I create checkboxes from this?

Comment: You will need to create your own custom form field. I answered a question very similar to this earlier on today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350220/custom-html-in-joomla-template-manager/20351844#20351844

Comment: I guess this is working (it does not produce any error), but how can I produce a checkbox for the every from the query? (I sorry to bothering you, but I am new to joomla, and everything about it is illogical to me at the moment (I went from CI to... whatever Joomla is) ).

Answer (score 0):

Your **custom.php** file in regards to the link I provided in the comments could look something like this:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class JFormFieldCustom extends JFormField {

    protected $type = 'Custom';

    protected function getInput() {

        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select($db->quoteName('*'));
         ->from($db->quoteName('#__content'));    
        $db->setQuery($query);     
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
        $result = array();

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $result['id'] = $row->id;
        }

        return $result;
    }

}
?>
```

Please bare in mind that this was a quick mockup and I haven't tested it so let me know if it works and I can make any adjustments if need be after :)

Comment: I am not getting a result - I have used **<field name="checkboxes" type="custom" default="" label="Articles" description="" />** and **<field name="image" type="custom" default="" label="Articles" description="" />** (from your original post) and the result is the same - blank input file.

Comment: I'll give it a test when I get back home

Comment: Just a quick update - I manage to get something, but now I have following error: **Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\joomla\libraries\joomla\form\field.php on line 869**

Comment: yeah I thought there might be an error somewhere or that it wouldn't work. I wasn't very confident as I had to write it quickly. I'll test it soon ;)

Comment: I did this thing, and I think I am getting somewhere (all the checkboxes are there):$result = '';
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            // $result['id'][] = $row->id;
            $result .= '<label>' . $row->title  . '</label><input type=checkbox name=article  value="' . $row->id .'"/>';
        }

Comment: So far so good - now I need a way to store checked boxes into DB, so I can retrieve them for the helper file. (I am sorry if I am bothering you, but I wanted to keep you updated, so you don't waste your time).

Comment: Hi, please ask a new question for this so the page doesn't get clogged up with everything :)

Comment: I asked a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358550/xml-field-checkboxes-with-sql-insert-checked-boxes-into-db-and-retrieve-result)

Answer (score 0):

You must create your own field or you can use this I created.
https://github.com/3ehrang/joomlaFields